Geo Data Extraction
I had a requirement to collect the schools, roads and some places in a Geopolygon (Coordinates) available me with me. Is there any suggestion for libraries or api's that can be helpful
I had tried Contextily library in Python but not useful

After installingosmnx, you could use features_from_polygon : import osmnx as ox; ox.features_from_polygon(polgon, {"amenity": ["school"], "highway": ["primary", ...]})
